# How can I send one bit one mile with one battery?

Tags: batteries, rf, wireless

This summer I will be attending a large music festival for the second year.  I will be going with other people this time, and I'd like to be able to communicate with the other people wirelessly in some way.  Cell phones are out, because even if you could get reception your phone dies quickly trying to fight with the other 50K+ cell phones in the square mile that the festival takes up.  Walkie talkies are difficult too- because there are so many people, nearly every channel is occupied.

I'm always open to reasonable commercial solutions but when faced with a problem like this my first thought is, what could I build?  I've got basic requirements:

- A bitrate of >0b/s.  Yes, that says bits per second.  0.1b/s would satisfy this requirement.
- A working distance of about 1km / 0.5 miles.  I'm willing to compromise here for...
- Pocket-sized and battery-powered.  Obviously not easy but this rules some tech out immediately.

I can use one bit to indicate "meet at the designated spot".  I can use four bits if we just sync up our maps with a legend.  So, I don't need practically any bandwidth at all, which might drastically simplify some designs.  Also, I'd be willing to get any licenses I needed to work on this, but I am not currently knowledgeable about RF communication.  I do have a strong basic electronics and programming background, though, so any ideas would be helpful.

I guess my basic question is:  is there a wireless tech available that meets the bulleted requirements and would not have the problem of being completely oversaturated by having 100K people in one square mile?

Comment: If the airwaves are full of traffic already, how do you expect your simple on/off Morse Code style thing to work properly without super awesome filtering skillz? I guess a very high quality RF transmit/receive pair with extremely good band-pass filtering could make use of an (illegal) unused frequency and it will probably work okay.

Comment: Just for you guys to communicate?  What about a 433mhz radio at low bit rate?  Or a teathered blimp and some modified laser pointers.  Kidding on the last one, sort of :)

Comment: @KyranF my thought process was, there might be some frequency- like says 433MHz- that isn't used by those common types of personal communication but that I could use, and that restricting the bandwidth of the frequency could possibly simplify the design.

Comment: What comes to mind is something like a smart meter communication method for remote areas where a low amplitude signal is sent multiple times at relatively lower frequencies. By the time the signal reaches the receiver, the signal is below the noise floor. The receiver is designed to track the frequency and when it compiles the noise over time, it can extract the information back out.

Comment: @Some Hardware Guy ...I can't come up with a good reason a tethered "blimp" wouldn't be perfectly acceptable in my situation.  Hmm.

Comment: What about to use a wireless USB network adapter like this http://www.amazon.com/Etekcity-Wireless-Network-Adapter-Antenna/dp/B006JWMOOI/ref=lp_13983791_1_24?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1421384016&sr=1-24

Comment: @KyranF Your question is exactly what he IS asking. IF the airwaves are full, how would I ... . There are many potential answers :-).

Comment: @TheNoonMoose  Burningman? Wrong continent for the UK hippiefests :-). Many potential options. Some easier. Almost certainly legal ISM (Industrial Scientific Medical) bands are available that have too low bandwidth for normal comms use. Old ISM/Radio control band at about 13.6 MHz in some admins. Multi channels at 27 MHz still used. "When the Robot points north ...". | Your local hams may be delighted to loan a spread spectrum low bandwidth unit that swims happily in the 2.4 GHz WiFi noise. | You may get better results with 5.x GHz WiFi - possibly not. | A narrow bandwidth signal "morse" ....

Comment: .... at a stable location in any band will allow a characteristic pattern to be picked out by ear at well under the noise level. Amateur morse code has always managed this.| Slow tone on a channel with a PLL detetctor would likely handle say 1 bps in vast noise and 0.1 bps in any amount of noise using simple majority presence voting. eg look for 400 Hz or 700 Hz - was there a predominance of either of these in the last second? | Correlation on two channels | SMALL tower - say 10 foot stick with an IR diode (or even a red LED - ....

Comment: .... or even a white visible LED but ability  to filter helps)  can give you vast range. As physical beam angle widens ease of comms connection increases. | Thinks - 1 mile red LED, a Watt or few - photo detector in a shielded tunnel or gallery to reduce ambient light. Sounds doable. Easily tried. Probably manage voice coms. Pocket size makes non directional RX harder. Worth a play. |FWIW with proper lenses and at night people manage voice coms out to about 50km | BUT workable is probably to find a common high point (or a blimp or few) and use sunlight and pocket mirrors :-)

Comment: [Too many ideas here](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=led+communicator&biw=1280&bih=717&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Tw25VPOyD8q68gX7koKQDg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=led+optical+link+communicator).| [Disney manage 50mm](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/schmist/papers/OWC12Slides.pdf)| and [Oh yes ! ](http://www.qsl.net/wb9ajz/laser/laser.htm) | and [Excessively tidy ](http://www.qsl.net/wb9ajz/laser/Kerry/Kerry%27s_OCB.html)

Comment: http://www.bluehaze.com.au/modlight/OpticalComms4Amateur79.htm

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Bonnaroo.  If you can make an answer about "morse" on a frequency I can use without a license I would accept that.

Comment: @TheNoonMoose Choose another good answer - and wait a few days - you may get even more good answers. A look at the ISM bands for your area will show what is legal. There are also sometimes bands in the VHF spectrum for ISM that are little known to low bandwidth. 
[ISM band info here - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band). I'd guess that 6.780 MHz is liable to be almost unknown and 13.567 MHz equally so. Both are very low bandwidth - about 1 voice channel (if allowed) or morse.

Comment: ...  Or low speed telemetry or data if allowed. Arduino .... :-).  They say " ...  In the United States of America, uses of the ISM bands are governed by Part 18 of the FCC rules, while Part 15 contains the rules for unlicensed communication devices, even those that share ISM frequencies ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amateur radio is perfect for that. Hand-held radios can reach several miles. You can use voice or morse if necessary. There is rarely any congestion, there may even be some repeaters. The initial test is pretty easy to pass as long as you get the manual.

Radios: http://www.aesham.com/ham-radios-handheld/?p=catalog&mode=catalog&parent=274&pg=1&CatalogSetSortBy=price

Study Guides: http://www.arrl.org/ham-radio-license-manual

Comment: My general assumption thus far has been that, given ~100K people in ~1 square mile, any common or easily accessible technology will already be used.

Comment: Given the number of channels open to amateur radio station operators in 70cm and 2m and the low density of operators, I think its safe to assume it wouldn't, especially since it requires an FCC license. For instance, I've taken my radio to the Imperial Sand Dunes near Yuma, AZ on holidays (50k people in a square mile) and its empty spectrum.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable answer, if a bit expensive and out of reach for my non-technical buddies.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: You could make use of a small FM bug with an RDS coder. Anyone with an off-the-shelf portable FM radio with RDS display would be able to receive your text information. Assembled FM bugs and RDS coders are easy to find, just a matter of putting it together.

Disclaimer: Transmitting on FM broadcasting channels with EIRP levels above -43dBm( 50nW) is illegal in most countries, so you could have problems with the 1km distance requirement if you do not want to break the law.

- Option 2: Use radio text messaging on a D-Star portable HAM transceiver. Widely available and if you and and your friends manage to get your HAM licence before the festival, that would probably be the most feasible option.
- Option 3: Acoustic OFDM. This allows simulcast of data and sound at low bit-rate via the speakers of the PA system. If you look at the size of festival speakers I don't think receiving decodable data at a distance of 1km is going to be a problem.

The downside is that you need to walk to the podium and get permission from the organiser to connect your device to the audiomixer or mike. Off-the-shelf devices are also very hard to come by.
The good thing is that you own a piece of technology that virtually nobody has ever seen, and that is going to make you cool @ the festival :).

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with a simple morse code process try a watch, a decent laser pointer and a convenient building. Everyone agrees to look at the building at the top and bottom of the hour and count the flashes they see on it.